# Memory compatibility - what to watch out for?

Tags: memory, compatibility

So, there's been at least 10 years since I adventure myself on the world of DIY computer upgrades. I have a desktop with 4GB of RAM and I need another 4GB.

But as soon as I re-entered the world of computer parts I learned that this thing called *memory compatibility* is a major deal right now. You should get the exact same model of your existing DIMM or the next best thing, to avoid problems.

So, what are the things (in order of imporance) to watch out for?
Frequency / Latency / Brand / Anything else?

Will a different brand with same latency and frequency work better than a same-brand with different latency and/or frequency?

Which is worse: different frequency or different latency?

Any help is greatly aprreciated because I went to three different stores and they all agreed that compatibility is a drag and I will definetly run into problems if I don't buy the right thing.

Sorry in advance for the multiple questions.

Comment: Stick to the RAM configurations explicitly listed in the user manual of your mainboard for best results, or rather, if you want someone to talk to should things go wrong. Says one who figured that deviations may not work. ;) Of course, you may as well buy similar stuff and get good results. It's just not guaranteed.

Comment: Voltage is another important factor these days. Freq vs CL is not a concern: the freq for the array will be based on the slowest chip in the array, and the JEDEC SPD profiles will determine the applicable timings and CL for the chips while opperating at that frequency.

Answer (score 0):

RAM will only run as fast as your slowest stick. Your motherboard's manual will have the specifics on what is the best configuration for your system but the things to keep in mind are:

Make sure you get the right generation RAM, DD3 or DD4 depending on the age of your board.
Make sure that all RAM is rated to run at the same voltage.
Make sure all ram is at the same frequency.
Try to get ram with the same, or as close to, CL as possible.

What channel configuration do you need? For best performance dual channel needs RAM installed in pairs of 2, triple channel in sets of 3, etc.

Brands don't matter much at all as long as the specs are the same but it is easier to match specs when you match brands.

Comment: So, this is my memory: http://www.gskill.com/en/product/f3-1600c11s-4gns
Would say it has a very good chance of being compatible with this one: http://www.gskill.com/en/product/f3-12800cl9d-4gbrl ?

Comment: in theory, JEDEC SPD profiles make all DDR3 compatible with all other DDR3 from a Freq/Bandwidth/Latency perspective, But in this case the chip configuration may cause issues (one link is a 1x single channel kit, the other link is a 2x chip dual channel kit). Also while both chips have been tested at 1600Mhz, one of them requires an XMP profile to reach it, and does not support that speed under SPD natively, so they should downgrade to 1333 at best. I'd recommend a differant pairing, with an even number of chips total, and there really isn't a good reason to get 1600Mhz ram instead of 1333.